# how to stop json.dump writing when user exists

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to stop `json.dump` writing into my JSON file when the user "account number" already exists.

This is my code:

```
new_student = {"name": 'test2', "account_no": 1237}
account_no = 1346
with open("student.json", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    for a in data["student_numbers"]:
        if not account_no == a["account_no"]:
            data["student_numbers"].append(new_student)
            with open("student.json", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
                json.dump(data, f)
            break
```

Here is my JSON as well:

```
{"student_numbers": [{"account_no": 1345, "name": "test"}, {"account_no": 1346, "name": "test2"}, {"account_no": 1347, "name": "test3"}]}
```

I tried `if account_no not in a["account_no"]` but I get this error:

> TypeError `TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable

Comment: and what do you want to see as result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your check is failing because when you iterate through `student_numbers`, these are the `account_no` being returned, namely: 1345, 1346, and 1347.  So you see in the very first iteration, your condition is already met because 1346 != 1345, so `json.dump()` is fired up.

What you want instead is create a list of `account_no` and use the `in` operator to check.  You don't need to iterate through `students_numbers`.

```
new_student = {"name": 'test2', "account_no": 1237}
account_no = 1346
with open("student.json", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    accounts = [a["account_no"] for a in data["student_numbers"]]
    if account_no not in accounts:
        data["student_numbers"].append(new_student)
        with open("student.json", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
            json.dump(data, f)
```

Comment: Thanks, this was well explained and helped me understand more

Comment: If you are copying and pasting the code, please do it again as I realized I messed up the indentations on mobile.

Comment: I just coped the bit I was missing. "accounts = [a["account_no"] for a in data["student_numbers"]]" and "if account_no not in accounts:" its working fine cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
new_student = {"name": 'test2', "account_no": 1237}
with open("student.json", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    existed_ids = {a['account_no'] for a in data["student_numbers"]}  # set of ids
    if new_student['account_no'] not in existed_ids:
        with open("student.json", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
            data['student_numbers'].append(new_student)
            json.dump(data, f)
```